# Getting around ruby-units conflict with activesupport

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use the ruby-units with a rails 3 project, but it seems like it conflicts with activesupport.

It looks to me like both activesupport and ruby-units create a to() method for String. For some reason, ruby-units one wins, and so whenever to() is called inside rails it throws an error. (Unit not recognized)

I want to know the best way to deal with this. I don't care about having the to() method from ruby-units, I just don't want it to interfere with rails. I'd like to avoid forking if there's another approach.

To see my problem:

Add to your gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-units'
```

Open up `rails console` (I'm on rails 3 with ruby 1.9.2) and try `apples.to(1)`

Without ruby-units:

```
"ap"
```

With:

```
"'apples' Unit not recognized"
```

Comment: Sorry, but couldn't reproduce your problem. I am using rails 3.1 and ruby-units 1.3.1 but whenever I use to on a String it does use the ActiveSupport version. Any other detail you're missing in your description?

Comment: Does the order in the gemfile matter for what order they're loaded in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is to require the ruby-units library before the rails library in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-units'
gem 'rails'
```

Obviously you then won't be able to use .to() on strings to access the ruby-units conversion.